# thread that call a webservice - how can I control thread State?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

suppose I have a thread (1) that call a webservice . As a result this thread go into Blocked state and other thread (2)start Running. what happen when the web service return (and thread 2 still running) ? does thread 1 will start Running again immediately or not ? can I control this ?

Comment: Threads normally gives you full concurrency, that means that each behave independently. When the web service returns then the thread will continue its job. What control do you want/need?

Comment: this is my question - can I be sure that  the thread will continue immediately  When the web service returns ? what if there is other running thread at that point ? suppose I have only one cpu

Comment: Don't you know what thread scheduling is? Multitasking?

Comment: I think I know .but I don't understand what you mean.again :suppose the web service return an answer - will thread 1 will continue immediately although thread 2 is running (will get block) ?

Comment: should I use Priorities ?

Comment: I found :when thread is reading data slow to arrive from a file, the JVM might stop the thread's execution and use a polling mechanism to determine when data arrives. While the thread remains stopped, the JVM's thread scheduler might schedule a lower-priority thread to run. Suppose data arrives while the lower-priority thread is running. Although the higher-priority thread should run as soon as data arrives, that doesn't happen until the JVM next polls the operating system and discovers the arrival. Hence, the lower-priority thread runs even though the higher-priority thread should run

Comment: You should not use any assumption on how the JVM realizes the thread scheduling. From the point of view of your thread, things are *normal*, data arrive, thread being blocked on reading is waked up for running again. What is the *really* your problem? Note: JVM may poll for asynchronous IOs realization on synchronous systems, but it doesn't seems to be your case, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Web Service library you are using will tell you. A good library will normally provide both options, with the distinction being the same method name with Async on the end, e.g.

```
get("www.google.com");       // Thread stops here, continues when request is done
getAsync("www.google.com");  // Thread continues running, you have to check whether the request is done when you want the result
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to control the Thread. Threads will take care of themselves and will run independently. You can create an interface and add a listener to the running thread so that it can notify the main thread when its finished doing its job.